# Facebook php app keeps looping in IE, is there a fix on server side?

Tags: php, facebook, internet-explorer, session, cookies

An iframe loading a php app keeps looping when I view it in IE. One fix is to lower the privacy setting in IE from Medium to Low.

Is there a workaround on the server side? I tried [the HTML header fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467326/facebook-app-works-on-all-browsers-but-not-ie8) but with no success. Are there other suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the infinite loop in IE using

```
<?php header('p3p: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"'); ?>
```

If not, you can try this setting on your Facebook

[image]

**[Source](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/facebook-apps-infinite-redirection-solution/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try putting channelUrl file and code,
see:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
 <script>
   document.domain = "mysite.com";
   FB.init({
     appId  : 'YOUR APP ID',
     channelUrl  : 'http://www,mysite.com/channel.html'  // custom channel
   });
 </script>
```

Contents of channel.html are :

```
<script> document.domain = "mysite.com"; </script>  
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```